# Attempting to fetch data from a list on Sharepoint and post it to a dropdown list on an external webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, sharepoint

My objective is to have an external web page that is a form. I am trying to fetch data from a sharepoint list and have been given this code to work with:

```
//Assuming Column1 is the parent column in sharepoint list and Column2 is child column
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var dropdown1 = document.getElementById('DropDown1');   //get dropdown1 by id
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById('DropDown2');   //get dropdown2 by id
var dropdown1Array=[];
var dropdown2Array=[];    //populate 1st dropdown
var call1 = $.ajax({
        url: "absolute URL" +  "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=column1",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    $.when(call1).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        data.d.results.forEach(function(entry) {
            //inserting unique values in dropdown1
            if (dropdownArray1.indexOf(entry.column1) == -1) { 
                dropdownArray1.push(entry.column1);
                //inserting items into dropdown1
                    var child = document.createElement("option");
                    child.textContent = entry.column1;
                    child.value = entry.column1;
                    dropdown1.appendChild(child);
                }
        });
    });
//populate 2nd dropwon in cascaded format
dropdown1.addEventListener("change", function () {
 while (dropdown2.firstChild) {
    dropdown2.removeChild(dropdown2.firstChild);
}
var call2 = $.ajax({
        url: "absolute URL" +  "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/Items?$select=column2&$filter=column1 eq dropdown1.value",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
    $.when(call2).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        data.d.results.forEach(function(entry) {
            //inserting unique values in dropdown2
            if (dropdownArray2.indexOf(entry.column2) == -1) { 
                dropdownArray2.push(entry.column2);
                //inserting items into dropdown2
                    var child = document.createElement("option");
                    child.textContent = entry.column2;
                    child.value = entry.column2;
                    dropdown2.appendChild(child);
                }
        });
    });
});                 
</script>
```

The thing is, I am having difficulty parsing and understanding the code, let alone getting it to work. I've copy and pasted the code into my web page in the body, but it does not work. I've tried to look over which parts I have to replace with real urls or titles, but I don't know where to start. I am not very good at SharePoint, and am requesting a more gentle breakdown of what I need to do to get this piece of code to work.

Comment: This is not gonna work outside of SharePoint. If you want to get data from SP to an external webpage, you should probably create a provider-hosted add-in. Even in a SharePoint-hosted add-in you have to pass in a validation token when making requests. (It might work if code is imbedded inside a SP-page, as script-editor web part or standalone .aspx-page)

Comment: What backend do you have for your webpage?

Comment: Currently none. I'm still in the process of making the front end first, and I've just only used HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery. I know some super basic form of Python, but really don't know how to connect it with the rest of my web page environment.

Comment: I wanted to use something like ASP, but I don't know enough about it to go about doing this project in ASP. I'm currently a student right now learning information systems, we're being taught HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery and PHP. I've done application coding in Visual Basic .NET. Python was picked up on the side due to my intrinsic values via codecademy Same with JavaScript. Any pointers or suggestions would be much appreciated. I am really motivated on finishing this web page.

Comment: Well, as i said, i don't think you will get this code working outside of SP. You can maybe try to create a console application in Visual Studio that gets the data through CSOM on a schedule and save it to some files. And then in your webpage, fill the dropdownlists with the contents of the files.